# "Styles" for PGFplots table expressions

Tags: pgfplots

Is it possible to use a style, or something equivalent, to specify the column expressions for `plot table`? The objective is to be able to use the same expressions for a large number of different plots with a minimum of repetitive typing.

Here is an example (which does not compile) that suggests what I would like to be able to do:

```
\documentclass{standalone}
\usepackage{pgfplots}
\pgfplotsset{/pgfplots/columns/.style={x=dof,y expr={\thisrow{L2}+\thisrow{Lmax}}}}
\begin{document}
 \begin{tikzpicture}
  \begin{loglogaxis}
   \addplot table[columns] {      % sample data from PGFplots manual
    dof     L2              Lmax            maxlevel
    5       8.31160034e-02  1.80007647e-01  2
    17      2.54685628e-02  3.75580565e-02  3
    49      7.40715288e-03  1.49212716e-02  4
    129     2.10192154e-03  4.23330523e-03  5
   };
  \end{loglogaxis}
 \end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Instead of setting

```
\pgfplotsset{/pgfplots/columns/.style={x=dof,y expr={\thisrow{L2}+\thisrow{Lmax}}}}
```

try

```
\pgfplotsset{table/columns/.style={x=dof,y expr={\thisrow{L2}-\thisrow{Lmax}}}}
```

Also, your end of line comment `% sample data from...` is interfering with the line

```
5       8.31160034e-02  1.80007647e-01  2
```

being plotted.

Comment: I moved the comment so it doesn't interfere with the data.

Answer (score 4):

When you use `\pgfplotsset` it is automatically the `pgfplots` key family but you need to wrap the column style in to some other key if you will selectively use it. Otherwise

```
\pgfplotsset{columns/.style={x=dof,y expr={\thisrow{L2}+\thisrow{Lmax}}}}
```

sets the style globally. And you can simply use

```
\addplot table {....};
```

without any options as the style is global. An example of selective use

```
\documentclass{standalone}
\usepackage{pgfplots}
\pgfplotsset{my col style/.style={columns/.append style={x=dof,y expr={\thisrow{L2}+\thisrow{Lmax}}}}}
\begin{document}
 \begin{tikzpicture}
  \begin{loglogaxis}
   \addplot table[my col style] {      % sample data from PGFplots manual
    dof     L2              Lmax            maxlevel
    5       8.31160034e-02  1.80007647e-01  2
    17      2.54685628e-02  3.75580565e-02  3
    49      7.40715288e-03  1.49212716e-02  4
    129     2.10192154e-03  4.23330523e-03  5
   };
   \addplot table[my col style] {      % sample data from PGFplots manual
    dof     L2              Lmax            maxlevel
    20       8.31160034e-02  1.80007647e-01  2
    137      2.54685628e-02  3.75580565e-02  3
    249      7.40715288e-03  1.49212716e-02  4
    5129     2.10192154e-03  4.23330523e-03  5
   };
  \end{loglogaxis}
 \end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: I'm not clear on what this is supposed to do. The data plotted in your example are just L2, not L2+Lmax as is supposed to be the case. (Sorry for the late response; I missed the notification about your answer.)